# VBA Selenium vs. HTML

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using VBA to access and download file but I'm strugling to find element.

I've got this piece of code which is perfectly working in browser console, but I'm not very familiar with selenium so I'm kindly asking you to help me with "translation" to VBA

```
($(".yui3-c-reportdashboardwidget-reportLabel[title='nameoftable']").parent()).find("a.ember-view").click();
```

For VBA I need

```
driver.FindElementByXpath().Click
```

or

```
driver.FindElementByCss().CLick
```

Thank you very much
P.

Answer (score 0):

i've found a solution, there exist "ExecuteScript" command in VBA.
so solution is:

```
driver.ExecuteScript ("$("".yui3-c-reportdashboardwidget-reportLabel[title='mytablename']"").parent().find('a.ember-view').click();")
```